# Where exactly are CSS functional pseudo-classes placed in overall CSS hierarchy and in relation to one another?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

When I tried to override some css classes in my project, I have noticed that even if I add my new class to the end of the css file, It is less important that the class with ':not()' which is higher.

':not()' is one of the functional pseudo-classes.

So, my conclusion is that functional pseudo-classes are more important than standard CSS classes.
If I wanted to override properties from class with pseudo-class, I would need to add to my new class the same pseudo-class as is used in the old class selector. Even if I add new class to the end of the CSS document.

Where exactly are CSS functional pseudo-classes placed in overall CSS hierarchy? Are some of the pseudo-classes more importand than other e.g :not() vs :nth-child()?

Comment: Does [this page](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity) help? I says that `:not()` itself is not counted as a pseudo class, but that everything inside counts normally.

Comment: If that doesn't help, could you create a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue?